# Disable Spring Security (ldap auth) Temporarily

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I have a simple web application, where username and password (entered in login page) are authenticated against LDAP using Spring Security.

Almost everything is configuration here. I can post all the config. files if necessary.

I need a way to disable this authentication altogether temporarily for the purpose of say demo/testing etc. Ideally if a 'do not authenticate' checkbox exists on login page, then authentication should be bypassed.

Ofcourse i can remove all Spring-Security stuff. But this is not really neat.

What is the simplest/best way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Which version of spring are you using ?

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227464/disable-spring-security-from-spring-security-xml-file

Comment: You can comment `DelegatingFilterProxy` in web.xml:
    `<filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a year old, but I ran across wanting to do this exact same thing. I could not find any way to do it dynamically but I did find a way so that a simple change that could be done on one line in `Config.groovy` and a restart of the app that worked for me.

`grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.active = false`

and then put the other ldap config options in an if statement

```
if (grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.active) {
    //All of the ldap options
 }
```