# Disable Spring Security via Java configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a Java application that uses Spring Security via Java configuration.

What is the easiest method of switching the whole Spring Security on/off in compilation?

So something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227464/disable-spring-security-from-spring-security-xml-file), but for a configuration that uses no XML.

EDIT:

After applying @Profile my code looks like:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("SecurityOn")
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

The problem is that if the profile "SecurityOn" is not activated, Spring Security uses some default configuration. Instead, how to turn Spring Security completely off in that case?

Answer (score 7):

To disable that behavior, you can add another class that looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@Profile("!SecurityOn")
public class WebSecurityConfigDisable extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
    }
}
```

Then, when you run your application, the only time you'll need to login will be when the `SecurityOn` profile is active. If you're using Maven and Spring Boot, the command to **enable** login would be the following.

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=SecurityOn
```

Running it without a profile, or a different profile, will **disable** login.  This is useful for local development.

I found this was necessary when using `spring-boot-starter-security` because there was default configuration which required login.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Profile](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) feature.

Since `@Profile` can be applied as method-level annotation on any `@Bean` method you can use single profile *(e.g. 'secure')* and annotate the relevant `@Bean` method(s) only.

Then specify the active profile(s) via either of the *JVM system properties, as an environment variable, or for web applications as a Servlet context parameter in `web.xml`*

Refer sample usage [here](http://www.captaindebug.com/2012/08/using-spring-profiles-and-java.html#.VKJv0MALaA).

Comment: Thanks! I have not used @Profiles so far, so this was a valuable lesson, but the problem persists. See EDIT in the question.