# How to temporarily disable Spring Security in Spring Web App

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

First, I am a complete noob when it comes to Spring.  An application was left to me to work on by a colleague who is now on vacation.  He told me to leave security alone, as the final approach is not decided yet, and just develop the rest of the application.

However security is enabled and prevents access to the main web page.  I've checked several documents including

[Disable Spring Security from spring-security.xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227464/disable-spring-security-from-spring-security-xml-file)

[Disable Basic Authentication while using Spring Security Java configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639188/disable-basic-authentication-while-using-spring-security-java-configuration)

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security.html

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-security.html

without finding an answer that works.

I did the following:

Added index.html to <welcome-file-list> in web.xml.  This directs me to the login page which was already included in the package I took over.  So, I figured I could simply disable security.

In the spring security.xml added the attribute security="none".  Now I no longer get the login page.  I get a blank page.

In web.xml disabled

```
<!--     <filter> -->
<!--        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> -->
<!--        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class> -->
<!--    </filter> -->

<!--    <filter-mapping> -->
<!--        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> -->
<!--        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> -->
<!--    </filter-mapping>  -->
```

Still get blank page.

I see lots of other advice, but it assumes a lot more Spring knowledge than I currently have.

For example in the 4th link above I see:

> If you define a @Configuration with @EnableWebSecurity anywhere in
>   your application it will switch off the default webapp security
>   settings in Spring Boot.

I don't know what they mean.  I assume this means to put these annotations on some method somewhere, but I can't believe that this can go ANYWHERE in any java class in the application.  Is there an example of doing this?

Can someone point me in the correct direction?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Comment out `<intercept-url pattern="" access="" />` tags in security XML file and give access to all the pages. This should work.

Comment: Yes, that's the same solution I posted.

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work (in spring-security.xml)

```
<!--        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" /> -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
```

Answer (score 0):

check your web.xml or your appContext.xml to find where is loaded the spring security.xml beans(it will be like `<import resource=../spring security.xml>`) and comment this out , also check the beans that are loaded from there before disabling it , cause it might redirecting or whatever